# Server error 500 when launching WordPress for the first time

Tags: wordpress, nginx, server

I just downloaded WordPress and started installing it. Unfortunately, after following all the instructions in the documentation (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lemp-on-ubuntu-22-04), I encounter an error when switching to my website.

I’ll note right away that I haven’t launched WordPress yet, when I go to the site, a window with WordPress settings should appear (selecting a language, creating a user), but instead I get an error - 500 Internal Server Error
nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

Here is data that may be useful -

The link I'm trying to access is http://charch/wordpress

Permissions on the folder charch = www-data:www-dataI will be very glad to receive your help! Thank you very much in advance!

[image: settings server]

/etc/hosts/ -
[image]

I will be very glad to receive your help! Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check your server logs for more information about the error.

Reupload the core WordPress files. If you have corrupted WordPress files, this will fix the problem.

Increase the PHP memory limit. If your PHP memory limit is too low, it can cause server errors. To increase the memory limit, you can edit your php.ini file or contact your web hosting provider.

Check your database for errors. If your database is corrupted, this can also cause server errors. To check your database, you can use a tool like phpMyAdmin.

Comment: You probably give good advice, but unfortunately, this all happens locally for me, my site is not hosted